# Assembly language, allocating memory in the stack

Tags: assembly, disassembly, machine-code

```
#define NORMAL_BUFFER_SIZE 32 
int getbuf()
{
    char buf[NORMAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
    Gets(buf);
    return 1;
}
```

I have a C code like this, and it should allocate 32 bytes in the stack.

When I disassemble it,

```
0804919e <getbuf>:
 804919e:   55                      push   %ebp
 804919f:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80491a1:   83 ec 38                sub    $0x38,%esp
 80491a4:   8d 45 d8                lea    -0x28(%ebp),%eax
 80491a7:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80491aa:   e8 ef f9 ff ff          call   8048b9e <Gets>
 80491af:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 80491b4:   c9                      leave  
 80491b5:   c3                      ret    
 80491b6:   90                      nop
 80491b7:   90                      nop
```

I get something like this, I can see that it allocates $0x38 bytes onto the stack first, and pass buf to Gets, as buf is an array, it is passing the base pointer to Gets. 
buf have a size of 32 bytes, that means 0x20 in hex, 
so why it is not passing lea -x020(%ebp), %eax?

As I know the structure of the stack should be something like this

```
--------------
ret addr
--------------
old ebp
--------------
32 bytes for
buf
--------------
something else
here
--------------
```

Comment: Is it for ret addr and ebp saver for Gets? So the first 32 bytes will be for buf and the next 8 bytes is for Gets?

Answer (score 1):

The stack frame structure is an implementation detail. The C language standard does not mandate it. So it could be anything, as long as local variables are there. No one ever promised that the frame would contain your local variables **and nothing else**.

In this case, you have an unused 8 byte chunk between saved EPB and `buf`, and another chunk below the `buf`. What for? Only the compiler knows. Maybe in the debug builds there's a stack protection cookie there, but the compiler wants to keep the stack frame layout consistent between debug and release builds. Maybe there's an alignment/padding requirement that is important for some scenario that your function does not exhibit.